# Change CSS if input value has specfic text ( Using plus minus buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have Input box with plus and minus buttons 
What I want is to **show  `div pete (display: block)`**  if input box reaches Value 50.
I tried using keyup but it only works if you manually put 50 value and not using plus minus buttons (in my case, I have disabled the input).

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vub686of/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="pete" style="display:none;">Pete</p>
<div class="sp-quantity">

  <div class="sp-minus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">-</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sp-input">
    <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="52" disabled />
  </div>
  <div class="sp-plus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">+</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input").val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }

  $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input").val(newVal);

});
$(".quntity-input").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value == "50") {
    $("#pete").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $("#pete").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.sp-quantity {
  width: 124px;
  height: 42px;
  font-family: "ProximaNova Bold", Helvetica, Arial;
}

.sp-minus {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.sp-input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-left: 0px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.sp-plus {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-left: 0px solid #e1e1e1;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.sp-input input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "ProximaNova Bold", Helvetica, Arial;
  border: none;
}

.sp-input input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border: none;
}

.sp-minus a,
.sp-plus a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.change()` instead?

Comment: @Fer Salas the change event is not fired for programmtic updates. You'd have to manually fire the event. To me, that's redefining the meaning of the event, so I'd just prefer to use a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tweaks and you're there. I think this is best achieved via a custom event on your input. See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLnm05md/11/).

```
var $button = $(this);
var inputControl =  $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");
var oldValue = inputControl.val();

if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
} else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
        newVal = 0;
    }
}

if (newVal != oldValue) {
    inputControl.val(newVal);
     inputControl.trigger( 'value-updated');
}


});

$(".ddd").closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input").on( 'value-updated', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "50" ) {
    $('p#pete').show();
  } else {
    $('p#pete').hide();
  }
});

$(".quntity-input").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value == "50") {
        $("#pete").css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
        $("#pete").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```